# How do I read columnar data in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm very used to [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), where I could just write:

```
m = load('test.dat');
```

`m` would be a a matrix of values in test.dat, as long as each line was formatted the same way. But in [Octave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave) it doesn't work:

I tried `fscanf`, but the documentation is very scanty:

```
fh = fopen('test.dat', 'r');
[m, count] = fscanf(fh, '%10s%10s%f');
```

`m` ends up as a single dimensional array of chars.

Suppose I have the following data:

```
03/12/2011    00:00      0.2151
...
```

How can I read this into a matrix in Octave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you consider to use `dlmread`?

However, if you are able to delimit the file like `03/12/2011,00:00,0.2151` then `csvread` will be able to handle it for you.

Comment: This is a good solution, but can you explain what scanf is doing?

Comment: @Dov: Well for `fscanf (fid, template, size)` from the documentation: 'The optional argument `size` specifies the amount of data to read and may be one of: ..., `Inf`; Read as much as possible, returning a column vector., ... and 'if `size` is omitted, a value of `Inf` is assumed'. Perhaps not so clear but study your documentation. And of'course it's always wise to stick with higher lever functions when ever thats possible. Thanks

Comment: This answer does not work. From the docs: "Note: only CSV files containing numeric data can be read. "       So dates and time fields will not be read in correctly. SOURCE: https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/csvread.html